# Is there a way I can put a fontawesome icon inside of data-content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Or is there any way to put any icon once I open up the popover? I tried to put an fontawesome icon inside of the box, but that didn't work out too well.

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("i.fa").popover({'trigger':'click'});
});
```

CSS:

```
[rel="popover"]{
        cursor: pointer;
        display:inline-block; /* chrome-fix */
    }
i.fa {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<i rel="popover" title="Share" data-dismiss="popover" data-content="hey" class="fa fa-share-alt fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Comment: Can I just say I absolutely hate how fontawesome uses the `<i>ITALICS</i>` tag for its icons? It makes no sense. Mind you I think it's long past time we ditched icon fonts in favour of SVG icons, they're so much easier to work with. You can even have more than a single colour in the icon :D -- I suppose I should say something about this question: If I understand correctly, you want to change the icon when you open the popover? In that case you just need to do something like `.removeClass('fa-share-alt').addClass('fa-other-icon')`

Comment: Yeah I agree with you @NiettheDarkAbsol. Also, not exactly what I meant, sorry. Like when I open the popover box, I want to see an icon inside the box. For example, Facebook will be inside of the popover when I hit that share button.